# Default value for frame_class

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a possibility to set a default value for frame_class?
I guess it could be something like this:

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        frame_class {
            default = none
        }
    }
}
```

`no frame` is the prefered default. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `TCAdefaults.tt_content.frame_class = none` Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use TCAdefaults for that.

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.frame_class = none
```

Comment: Looks valid. I tried it, but frame-classes still appear in frontend. Some more information:
- My installation runs on PHP 7.1 and TYPO3 8.7.9 (updated from 6.2).
- I used the snippet in Page TS (via file and also direct via backend).
- Of cause I cleared all caches ;)
- I also tried it on another instance: no effect
Did I miss something?

Comment: This will only work for new elements. Already existing elements are not effected, since the value is already in the database.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense … I'll write a migration.
Thanks :)